# Create AD user if they don't exist, update if they do exist

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a .csv file with user data and a script using if/else that uses Get-ADUser to determine whether the account already exists.
If the user does exist, the script updates the user. If the user doesn't exist, all I get is an error saying "Cannot find an object with identity: 'bob.roberts'.
It seems to be skipping the else portion of the script.
Here's a sanitized version of the script I'm using:

```
    $Users = Import-Csv -Path "\\path\to\user.csv"

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $Displayname = $User.Lastname + ", " + $User.Firstname
    $UPN = $User.SAM + "@" + $User.Domain

    if (Get-ADUser $User.SAM)
    {
       Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SAM -Enabled: $true -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Office $User.Office -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -Country CA -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax
       Move-ADObject -TargetPath $($User.OU)
    }
    else
    {
       New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -Enabled: $true -Path $User.OU -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $User.SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $User.Firstname -Surname $User.Lastname -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $true -OtherAttributes @{'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName'=$User.Office;'Pager'=$User.Pager;c="CA";co="Canada";countrycode=124}
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    if ($User.ADGroup -ne "null")
    {
       Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $User.ADGroup -Members $user.SAM
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something (probably something obvious), but what?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if / else` you should use `try / catch`

> When you run a command that causes an error, the command will do what
>   is called throwing an exception. Using a try/catch block, it allows
>   you to gracefully handle that exception, and perform actions to
>   resolve the problem that may otherwise cause your script to break.

I like this quote from https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/63n6ij/ifelse_versus_trycatchfinally/

If you wrap your command in `try / catch` and add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-ADUser` the code will stop and jump into the catch block if `Get-ADUser` throws an error. Otherwise it will continue executing the `try` block. you also won't get an errormessage this way if a AD-User is not found.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "\\path\to\user.csv"

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $Displayname = $User.Lastname + ", " + $User.Firstname
    $UPN = $User.SAM + "@" + $User.Domain

    Try {
        Get-ADUser $User.SAM -ErrorAction Stop
        Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SAM -Enabled: $true -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Office $User.Office -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -Country CA -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax
        Move-ADObject -TargetPath $($User.OU)
    }
    Catch {
        New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -Enabled: $true -Path $User.OU -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $User.SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $User.Firstname -Surname $User.Lastname -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $true -OtherAttributes @{'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName'=$User.Office;'Pager'=$User.Pager;c="CA";co="Canada";countrycode=124}
    }

    Start-Sleep -s 2

    if ($User.ADGroup -ne "null")
    {
       Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $User.ADGroup -Members $user.SAM
    }
}
```

You could also save the result of `Get-ADUser` in a variable and check if the variable is empty or not with `if / else` but I would recommend `try / catch`.

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser $User.SAM -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($ADUser)
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SAM -Enabled: $true -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Office $User.Office -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -Country CA -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax
    Move-ADObject -TargetPath $($User.OU)
}
else
{
    New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -Enabled: $true -Path $User.OU -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $User.SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $User.Firstname -Surname $User.Lastname -Description $User.Description -Title $User.Title -Company $User.Company -Department $User.Department -Email $User.Email -StreetAddress $User.Street -City $User.City -State $User.Province -PostalCode $User.PostalCode -OfficePhone $User.Telephone -Fax $User.Fax -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $true -OtherAttributes @{'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName'=$User.Office;'Pager'=$User.Pager;c="CA";co="Canada";countrycode=124}
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for that and I will give it a try. I found that modifying my initial 'if' statement to 'if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Sam})' no longer throws an error, and will create the user if they don't already exist. I'll have to view the reddit quote from home (we block reddit at work). I can see where try/catch would execute faster in a complex script, but I was expecting the entire 'if' block to be skipped if the Get-ADUser failed.

Comment: @AndrewPenner with try/catch the entire if block you had in your question will also be skipped, since it stops after `Get-ADUser` if it fails.

Comment: @AndrewPenner btw. I don't think your `move-adobject` will work right now, since you don't tell the command which ADObject you want to move